# Can you play multiple cards together of the same number but different colors?

Tags: uno

During an Uno game, can one player put multiple cards of the same number but not the same color on top of each other, with the first card the same as the previous one in the Discard Stack?

Answer (score 4):

You may only play a single card each turn and note the rules mention playing "a card" not multiple.

[Rules](https://www.unorules.com/)

> You have to match either by the number, color, or the symbol/Action. For instance, if the Discard Pile has a red card that is an 8 you have to place either a red card or a card with an 8 on it. You can also play a Wild card (which can alter current color in play).

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is a common house rule in Uno, that you can play multiple cards of the same value in a single play.  This is not in the official rules of Uno, and as such, there is no canonical answer other than ["this is not allowed"](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/51279/9999).  However, having played under the house rule, it usually goes like this:

- You can play multiple cards of the same value as a single play, even if they are different values.
- The bottom card must match the value or color of the previous top of the stack, but beyond that, you choose the order of the other cards that you play.
- If the cards are numeric, there is no effect other than you having played multiple cards.
- If the cards are a special effect, that effect is applied multiple times

  - Draw 2 or Draw 4: the value adds together, so three Draw 2's means draw 6 cards
  - Skip: skip a number of players equal to the number of skips played
  - Reverse: reverse a number of times equal to the reverses played; this equates to no effect with an even number of reverses and a regular reverse effect with an odd number
- You can't go out on a play of multiple cards.  You must keep one of them in hand, declare "Uno", and then try to play it next turn.

This house rule has the advantage of allowing players who have gotten many extra cards to have a better chance of coming back (as the more cards you have, the more you will likely have with the same number).

I have typically seen this house rule played with the additional rule:

- If someone plays Draw 2s or Draw 4s against you, you can add any number of Draw X card of the same type to pass it on to then next player, with your cards adding to the total needing to be drawn (ex. someone plays two Draw 2s against you; you can play one Draw 2 to make the next player draw 6 cards).